# Plotting a bar graph of a variable using only outliers in the record found already

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to construct a bar graph of a variable **Deal** using outlier records that I have found from standardizing my variable of net profit. I am trying to make the bar graph with only the records from deal that are outliers based upon the standardized netprofit column.

To begin, the two columns or variables I am working with are Deal and netprofit.

I started with

```
data_2$netprofit_z <- scale(x = data_2$netprofit)

data_2[which(data_2$netprofit_z < -3 | data_2$netprofit_z > 3),]

netprofit_outliers <- data_2[which(data_2$netprofit_z < -3 | data_2$netprofit_z > 3),]
```

This gives me 64 values from data_2 that are outliers.

I used;

```
ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

This gives me all the records in data_2 of Deal, however I can't seem to figure out how to graph only the values of Deal that are outliers based from netprofit_outliers.

I have tried

```
ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar(aes(netprofit_outliers)) + coord_flip()

ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = netprofit_outliers)) + coord_flip()

ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = data_2$netprofit_outliers)) + coord_flip()
```

The last one actually managed to spit out the same as;

```
ggplot(data_2, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

Which Rstudio said was discouraged, and it doesn't help me as I need to get only the outlier responses in Deal.

Using `dput(netprofit_outliers)` I get

```
> Deal = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No"
)
```

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Please `dput()` your data and add the result to your question, this will help provide an answer. Thanks

Comment: I added in the dput() of the outliers. Thank you for that, I can now at least compare between the ratio of outliers versus the ratio that's not.

Comment: We need `dput(data_2)`

Comment: the answer is `ggplot(netprofit_outliers, aes(Deal)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()` I only figured it out after messing with it for awhile, that I need to do a graph of just the outlier dataset that I created with `netprofit_outliers <- data_2[which(data_2$netprofit_z < -3 | data_2$netprofit_z > 3),]` rather than the entire dataset.